# Tikz creating and array of images with a box around some

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to create a collection of images that look like this:

[image]

I would love to use some code so I can specify the image, the array size and also the box location, say: `\FracObj{object}{number of rows of the object}{number of columns of the object}{first row of box}{first column of box}{last row of box}{last column of box}`

for example the above image would be `\FracObj{critter}{4}{3}{1}{2}{1}{3}`.

The code doesn't have to match this exactly, just keen for that level of specificity. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Change [`row sep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#tikz/row:sep) and [`column sep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#tikz/column:sep) as well as the [`inner sep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/inner:sep) and [`outer sep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/outer:sep) to change the space between the images (inner sep + row/column sep) as well as the padding of the box around them (inner sep + outer sep).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % loads graphicx
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\repeatMe[2]{%
  \ifnum#1=0 \expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
    {#2\expandafter\repeatMe\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\fracobjset{\pgfqkeys{/fracobj}}
\fracobjset{
  rows/.initial=4,
  cols/.initial=3,
  matrix/.style={row sep=.4em, column sep=1.5ex},
  node/.style={
    name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
    inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+.125em},
  box path/.style={to path={rectangle(\tikztotarget)}},
  size/.style args={#1 by #2}{rows={#1}, cols={#2}},
  graphics/.initial={height=2em},
  box/.style args={#1 to #2}{matrix/.append style={append after command={
        (\tikzlastnode-#1.north west) edge[/fracobj/box path]
        (\tikzlastnode-#2.south east)}}}}
\newcommand{\fracObj}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fracobjset{#1}
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/fracobj/graphics}\fracObjGraphicsOptions
\matrix[/fracobj/matrix]{
  \repeatMe{\pgfkeysvalueof{/fracobj/rows}}{
    \repeatMe{\pgfkeysvalueof{/fracobj/cols}}{
      \node[/fracobj/node]{%
        \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\fracObjGraphicsOptions]{#2}};
      \unless\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\pgfkeysvalueof{/fracobj/cols}\relax
        \expandafter\pgfmatrixnextcell\fi}
  \unless\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\pgfkeysvalueof{/fracobj/rows}\relax
    \expandafter\pgfmatrixendrow\fi}
\pgfmatrixendrow};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\fracObj[box=1-2 to 1-3]{example-image-1x1}

\fracObj[box=1-2 to 1-3,
         box=2-1 to 3-2,
         box=2-3 to 3-4,
         size=3 by 4,
         graphics={height=1.5em},
         box path/.append style={rounded corners=2pt}
]{example-image-1x1}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]